# Is there a way I can set opacity using jQuery that works for all browsers?

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following:

```
$titleSpan.css('visibility','visible');
$titleSpan.css('visibility','hidden');
```

This makes my text appear visible or hidden.

However I would like to change this so the text has a visibility of 50%. I read there are problems with IE and it works differently. Because of this I am wondering if jQuery has a way to set it.

How could I change these two CSS lines so that the first makes the text fully visible and the second makes it have an opacity of 50%?

Comment: `fadeTo()` with a duration of 0?; http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

Comment: if it needs to be css, look up csshooks http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [.fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) method:

```
$(elem).fadeTo(0, .5);
```

Comment: Will this work for the text inside my span as the id I have is for the id of the span? Also how can I make it appear again?

Comment: Anne, seems logic, if `0` represents the `fade time` and `.5` (0.5) the `opacity`...